# Delphi: звук TrayIcon

Tags: delphi, system-tray, playsound

В Delphi имеется компонент TrayIcon для создания иконки в трее задач Windows. Также данный компонент позволяет создавать "Уведомления". Можно указать текст сообщения, время до сокрытия и другие параметры. Когда появляется такое "Уведомление" проигрывается соответствующий системный звук.

Мой вопрос состоит в том, можно ли изменить этот системный звук на свой пользовательский или хотя бы убрать его при наступлении "Уведомления"?

```
procedure ShowBallon(aText: string);
begin
  Form1.TrayIcon1.Visible := True;
  Form1.TrayIcon1.Animate := True;
  Form1.TrayIcon1.BalloonHint := aText;
  Form1.TrayIcon1.ShowBalloonHint;
end;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Компонент `TTrayIcon` является оберткой WinApi-функции `Shell_NotifyIcon` (это можно выяснить, если заглянуть в реализацию метода `ShowBalloonHint`).

Идем в msdn, ищем описание: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shell_notifyiconw

Функция принимает на вход структуру `NOTIFYICONDATA`, в описании которой https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-notifyicondataa сказано, что если в поле `dwInfoFlags` установить флаг `NIIF_NOSOUND`, то звук воспроизводиться не будет.

Далее по исходникам видим, что поле структуры `dwInfoFlags` заполняется данными из свойства класса `BalloonFlags`.

Но в типе `TBalloonFlags` нет флага, соответствующего `NIIF_NOSOUND`

Можно попробовать перед вызовом сделать следующий фокус:

```
Form1.TrayIcon1.BalloonFlags = TBalloonFlags(Cardianl(Form1.TrayIcon1.BalloonFlags) OR NIIF_NOSOUND);
```

перед вызовом `ShowBalloonHint`.

Возможно потребуется отключить какие-нибудь проверки компилятора.

Если не сработает, придется писать свой класс-наследник от `TTrayIcon` и перегружать метод `ShowBalloonHint`, благо он виртуальный.

**PS**

Изменить звук не получится, т.к. он устанавливается в свойствах оболочки (Shell)

Comment: Спасибо за понятный и развернутый ответ.